# Using h-entry and schema.org at the same time

Tags: seo, schema.org, microdata

Is it ok to use both Microdata h-entry and schema.org in the same template? Or better to use one of them?

Comment: Do you really mean `h-entry` with Microdata (instead of Microformats)? (just asking, because while it’s possible to use Microdata, it’s rather uncommon and most use Microformats)

Comment: Sounds it's better to use 1 of microdata type.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of redundancy. [Google's validation tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) only detects and reads these h-entry classes:

```
entry-title
author
updated
```

But appears to validate a broader number of schema objects. Whether Google uses them or not is very hard to determine and often changes. If you'd like to make sure it's using at least one, use both. If you're comfortable using one version or the other, then do that.